# GSAP animation with bezier curve

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I wanna create a car animation by using green sock's TweenMax.js.

As the pic shown below, the car drives from point1 to point4, but the line of point2 to point3 is in a bezier curve.
How can I make it works?! please help~ thanks alot~

[pic example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14537723/test.jpg)

Here's my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
TweenMax.to( document.getElementById("car"), 10, {
    bezier: {
        type: "cubic",
        values: [
            { x: 1200, y: 445 }, 
            { x: 900, y: 520 },
            { x: 660, y: 600 }, 
            { x: 0, y: 500 }
        ],
        autoRotate: false,
    }, 
    ease: Power1.easeInOut,
    repeat: -1
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to animate along a cubic bezier curve you need at least four points per segment, since each Segments consists of a starting and endpoint, plus two control points. In your code you describe a line, starting at `1200, 445`, to `0,500`, with controlepoints at `900,520` and `660,600`.

Comment: This was answered in the GreenSock forums on the duplicate post: http://forums.greensock.com/topic/9966-straight-path-animation-with-one-bezier-curve/